# How to get the Rotation of an Object as a Vector3?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am modeling an acceleration device. For this purpose I want to Accelerate the Object in the direction, it is pointing. My Idea was to have a vector for the default direction and then i rotate this vector according to the rotation of the transform. Therefor i tried using this code:

```
Vector3 defaultDirection = (1f, 0f, 0f);
Vector3 rotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
Debug.Log("x: " + rotation.x);
Debug.Log("y: " + rotation.y);
Debug.Log("z: " + rotation.z);
```

The Problem is the first time i try to execut it, the output is as follows:

```
x:0,3876027
y:0,004236011
z:0,38655568
```

The Object, as well as all parents, have a rotation of `0, 0, 0`. I double checked it. What am I doing wrong? Or is this just inaccuracy, caused by the casts?

**EDIT:** To make this clear, my Problem is not that i can not rotate the default vector to the rotation vector. My Problem is that i get wrong Values for the rotation vector. it should be 0, 0, 0 but the output is showing me other values.

Comment: Do you just want to rotate an object to a position? Then use [RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html). If you want an object to look at something you can use [LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html). Can you clarify your question a bit?

Comment: @TEEBQNE In the end i need a Vector with a lentgh of 1, that points towards the front of my Object.,so i can accelerate it. If there is a way to do this without using the rotation, pls let me know. Otherwise i need the correct rotation first, and then i can think about how I use the vector.

Comment: If you want to convert type Quaternion to Vector3, then you should use `Vector3 other = new Vector3(rot.x, rot.y, rot.z);` make sure rot is a type Quaternion. It works by taking three float value, and then putting them into a type Vector3.

Comment: @ken Thanks. This is the answere I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You will have to clarify your question a bit if you want a good answer**, however I think that you are asking how to rotate an object so it is facing a position specified by another transform/Vector 3. *(If that is not the case I do apologize).*

Unity provides great documentation and an API that might be able to help as well:

- [Transform.RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html) (rotates the GameObject's forward vector towards the target object's position by a specified increment)
- [Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) (manipulates the GameObject so the object's forward vector is pointing toward target object)

If you are just storing the value use: `rotationValue = new vector3(x, y, z) //Creates a new vector3 called rotationvalue that contains the eulerAngles of your rotation`

Above, in a comment to @TEEBQNE you mentioned that you want "a vector with a length of 1 that points toward the front of your object". You could use `gameobject.transform.forward` to get a vector that does this.

best!

Comment: You are right about what i want to do. But the problem is not that i can not use `RotateTowards` or  `LookAt`. The Problem is that I get incorrect values for the Vector i wanna rotate to.

Comment: @Tobias I still don't think I understand your question completely. Above you mentioned in a comment to @TEEBQNE that you want "a vector with a length of 1 that points toward the front of your object". You could use `transform.forward` to get a vector in local space that has a length of one.

Comment: Yep, the direction of `transform.forward` multiplied by a scaler will give you some acceleration in that direction. You can also use `AddForce` in the direction to get a more realistic physics outcome

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 defaultDirection = new Vector3(1f,0f,0f);
        obj.eulerAngles = defaultDirection;
        Debug.Log("x: " + obj.rotation.eulerAngles.x);
        Debug.Log("y: " + obj.rotation.eulerAngles.y);
        Debug.Log("z: " + obj.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
```

here try :)

NOTE = "obj" is a transform.

Answer (score 0):

This gets the actual world rotation of the object:

```
Vector3 rotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
```

This prints it:

```
Debug.Log("x: " + rotation.x);
Debug.Log("y: " + rotation.y);
Debug.Log("z: " + rotation.z);
```

So, your code just prints the actual object's world rotation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).